# Проверка на не заполненные поля...

Tags: javascript, html

Имеются поля для пк версии и моб. версии:

```html
<div class="small--hide">
<p align="right" style="margin-top:30px;">
<a href="/cart/oneclick/" class="btn btn--secondary cart__update cart__continue--large" >Вернуться назад</a>
<input id="1" type="submit" class="add-cart btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn" name="submitdata" value="Оформить заказ" />
</p>
</div>


<div class="site-header__menu">
<p style="margin-top:30px;">
<a href="/cart/oneclick/" target="_blank" style="color: #3d4246">Вернуться назад</a>
<input id="2" type="submit" class="add-cart btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn" name="submitdata" value="Оформить заказ" />
</p>
</div>
```

Есть скрипт проверки на пустые поля

```js
<script>
$("#1").on("click", function() {
 console.log('!!!');
  $("div.error").remove();
  if ($("#order_fio").val().length < 1) {
 console.log('!!!');
 $("#order_fio").addClass('input--error');
    return false;
  }
    if ($("#order_phone").val().length < 1) {
 console.log('!!!');
 $("#order_phone").addClass('input--error');
    return false;
  }
});
$(document).on('focus','input,select,textarea',function(){$(this).removeClass('input--error')});
</script>
```

С пк версии если поля пустые то не пропускает дальше при нажатии на кнопку "Оформить заказ", поля обводятся красным. А вот с моб версии ничего не происходит и свободно пропускает дальше...

Comment: Дубликат от того же человека https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805057/Не-работает-проверка-на-пустые-поля?noredirect=1#comment1273406_805057

Comment: А зечем у вас два input type="submit" в форме? А в скрипте обработка только $("#1") По поводу клика попробуйте добавить  touchstart к обработчику .on('click touchstart',....

Comment: @Heidel, этот человек не благонадежен. По ссылочке выше немного подробностей